# How to handle .net4.5 requirement issue in windows for electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, squirrel.windows

We have our desktop app (windows) built in electron.
On most of the system, it gets installed perfect. But in some computers, specially windows 7, user gets prompt to install .net 4.5 before installing software. Most of the case, installing this works fine. But in some case, user wont be able to install .net 4.5 since newer version of .net is installed in their system. In that case, we need to do remote connection to their PC and uninstall previous version and install new version with some tweak..i.e, stoping WuAuServ, and something with softwareDistribution and starting WuAuServ again.

It seems its requirement for apps built with electron.

I was wondering if even slack faces the same issue while installing. If not then can somebody guide me on what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is your Electron app that requires net framework? As far as I know Electron have no such dependency. Could it be your installer or some other prerequisite? What are you using to generate the installer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I am using 'electron-winstaller' for creating installer. Using 'electron-squirrel-startup' for installation and update processes.

Comment: Then that's your problem, Squirrel needs net framework. Your Electron app probably doesn't (unless you've used some weird npm packages) so I would raise this problem on [electron-winstallers issue tracker](https://github.com/Aluxian/electron-windows-installer/issues) (or possibly electron-squirell-startup) to see if this is a known problem.

Comment: Thanks.. I have raised an issue both in electron-squirrel-startup and electron-winstaller. Hope i get some good solution.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren can you please help me out with creating an installer. I am trying to do with electron-builderand i am using nsis, but i cannot find any option for remote release where i can give the url of my previous version to generate delta package. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I've never done delta updates with any installer packages. I just redistribute the whole application with each release.

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering if slack also does the same?

Comment: I have no idea how they manage updates to their client, that would be something you'd have to ask the developers about.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done with this electron specifically, but InnoSetup is a super installer. It's just that though, an installer. Updates are a different thing, but two main approaches come to mind: there's an n package (or maybe multiple) for doing electron updates, and there are also various binary patch tools around as well.